# Linking Excel Checkbox using VBA to a cell in another Worksheet

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I am relatively new to Excel VBA. I have found the following code online to add multiple check boxes in excel in a particular worksheet (Let's call it Sheet 1):

```
Sub AddCheckBoxes()
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim c As Range, myRange As Range
   Set myRange = Selection
   For Each c In myRange.Cells
   ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height).Select
   With Selection
   .LinkedCell = c.Address
   .Characters.Text = ""
   .Name = c.Address

   End With
   Next
   myRange.Select
  End Sub
```

As seen above, each check box is linked to the cell it is located in. What I am trying to do is find out a way to link the result of the check box (True, False) to another sheet (let's call it worksheet 2) in the same excel file. For example, if I were to click a checkbox on row W9 on sheet 1, it should say True on W9 on sheet 2. Is there a way to tweak the above code to make that work?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can change

```
.LinkedCell = c.Address
```

to something like

```
.LinkedCell = "Sheet2!" & c.Address
```